# Cumbersome JQuery Selector

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm trying to teach myself some simple JQuery and come up with the following menu system.  It is a basic nested UL and LI based menu with the inner UL being shown with JQuery .show() and hidden with .hide().  The HTML is as follows:-

```
    <ul id="menu1" class="gtrmenu">
        <li><span class="parent"><img class="hidden-bg" src="images/arrow-down.png"/>Single Menu</span> 
            <ul class="children">
                    <li><a href="#">Blah blah</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Drivel</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Select something</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Choose me!!</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>

    <ul id="menu2" class="gtrmenu menugroup2">
        <li><span id="menu2click" class="parent"><img class="hidden-bg" src="images/arrow-down.png"/>Grouped Menu</span>    
            <ul class="children">
                    <li><a href="#">Something here</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">More Stuff</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Waffle etc</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>

    <ul id="menu3" class="gtrmenu menugroup2">
        <li><span id="menu3click" class="parent"><img class="hidden-bg" src="images/arrow-down.png"/>Search</span>  
            <ul id="searchX" class="children">
                <li>
                    <form>
                        <input id="search" type="text" name="firstname">
                    </form>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>        

    <p>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog</p>
```

The Javascript and JQuery is as follows:-

```
function gtrMenu(menuID, groupClass, clickElement) {

    if (clickElement === undefined) {
        clickElement = menuID;
    }

    $(menuID + ' ul').css("minWidth", $('#menu1').width());

    $(clickElement).click(
        function() {   

            if ($(menuID + ' ul.children').is(":hidden")) {

                // Close any open menus within the same group.
                if (groupClass !== undefined){
                    $('ul.gtrmenu.' + groupClass + ' li ul.children:visible').not(menuID).closest('ul.gtrmenu').each(function(index){
                        //console.log(index + " " + $(this).attr("id"));
                        $(this).find('li .parent img').removeClass('visible-bg').addClass('hidden-bg');
                        $(this).find('ul.children').hide();
                    });
                }

                // Change style of arrow image.
                $(menuID + ' li .parent img').removeClass('hidden-bg').addClass('visible-bg');

                // Display the submenu
                $(menuID + ' ul.children').show();

            }
            else {

                // Revert style of arrow image.
                $(menuID + ' li .parent img').removeClass('visible-bg').addClass('hidden-bg');

                // Hide the submenu.
                $(menuID + ' ul.children').hide();

            }
        }
    );
}
```

The Javascript is run by the following (it wouldn't format correctly as part of the HTML above, so I've added it here):-

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            gtrMenu("#menu1");
            gtrMenu("#menu2", "menugroup2" , "#menu2click");
            gtrMenu("#menu3", "menugroup2" , "#menu3click");
        });
```

The menu can be a single menu, as demonstrated by 'Single Menu' (menu1); or it can be grouped, as demonstrated by 'Grouped Menu' (which is grouped with 'Search') above (menu2 & menu3).  In a grouped menu, only one can be open at a time - if a user has 'Grouped Menu' open and clicks on 'Search', 'Grouped Menu' closes.

I very proud to say that it all works :-)  However, my selector for finding the open menu within the group above seems very long and cumbersome to me (it's the line above the commented out console.log line).  My question is:  Is there a simpler way to find the menus within the group that are already open (so that they can be closed)?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you are not using the same classes for other purposes, you can actually shorten your selector by removing unnecessary specificity. Additionally, you can remove the `closest` method by using a `has` selector:

```
$('.gtrmenu.' + groupClass + ':has(.children:visible)').not(menuID)
```

This said, I would actually recommend you keep the specificity, just to make it less likely you select something you didn't intend to.

```
$('ul.gtrmenu.' + groupClass + ':has(li ul.children:visible)').not(menuID)
```

Comment: Brilliant.  I've just read the JQuery docs on :has() and it's exactly what I needed.  I thought that selecting down the path until I found the correct element, then backing off to it's parents was not the best way to do it.